# Fragment not being replaced, be placed on top of other fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am slowly converting my app to fragments vs activities, and I am getting some odd behavior at the moment. I have a button that when pressed should load a new fragment into view then execute an async task in order to load information into the fragment.

My code for the fragment which contains the button to swap the new fragment is:

```
public class Discover extends Fragment {
    Fragment Fragment_one;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_discover, container, false);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
        String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

        //add button onclick programatically
        Button bt = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.discoverBeers);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do whatever stuff you wanna do here
                FragmentManager man=getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction tran=man.beginTransaction();
                Fragment_one=new BPTopBeers();
                tran.add(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
                tran.addToBackStack(null);
                tran.commit();
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //todo: change to discover layout
        return v;

    }
```

I know it loading on top of the other fragment and not swapping because I can see the other fragment below it:

[image]

The fragment that is loaded on the button click is:

```
public class BPTopBeers extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toptaste_layout, container, false);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
        String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

        String title = "Top Beers on Beer Portfolio";
        TextView topTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.topTasteTitle);
        topTitle.setText(title);


        //construct url
        String url = "myURL";

        Log.d("myUrl", url);

        //async task goes here
        new GetYourTopTasteBeers(getActivity()).execute(url);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        return v;

    }
```

and the async task which is called in that fragment looks like this:

```
public class GetYourTopTasteBeers extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context c;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog;

    public GetYourTopTasteBeers (Context context)
    {
        c = context;
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Getting beers");

        Dialog.setTitle("Loading");
        Dialog.setCancelable(false);
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        //decode json here
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);


            //acces listview
            ListView lv = (ListView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.topTasteBeers);

            //make array list for beer
            final List<ShortBeerInfo> tasteList = new ArrayList<ShortBeerInfo>();



            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                String beer = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("beer");
                String rate = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("rate");
                String beerID = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
                String breweryID = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("breweryID");


                int count = i + 1;

                beer = count + ". " + beer;


                //create object
                ShortBeerInfo tempTaste = new ShortBeerInfo(beer, rate, beerID , breweryID);

                //add to arraylist
                tasteList.add(tempTaste);


                //add items to listview
                ShortBeerInfoAdapter adapter1 = new ShortBeerInfoAdapter(c ,R.layout.brewer_stats_listview, tasteList);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter1);

                //set up clicks
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        ShortBeerInfo o=(ShortBeerInfo)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

                        String tempID = o.id;
                        String tempBrewID = o.brewery;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(c, tempID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();

                        //todo: change fragment to beer page

                        //Intent myIntent = new Intent(c, BeerPage2.class);
                        //myIntent.putExtra("id", tempID);
                        //myIntent.putExtra("breweryID", tempBrewID);
                        //c.startActivity(myIntent);


                    }
                });




            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        Dialog.dismiss();

    }

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: show your layout file

Comment: try replace instead of add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `add` it just straight add the fragment to the view however when you use `replace`  it removes the current fragment then adds the new one which is what you are looking for since it appears your XML is not set to `match_parent`

Answer (score 0):

You can hide old fragment,if you want to back to previous

```
fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .hide(previous fragment)
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
            .add(R.id.content_frame, newFragment,
                ParserConstants.FRAGMENT_MAIN).addToBackStack(null)
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: would I use this if I want to add back button feature, to go back to a fragment?

Comment: if you press back button - you back  to previous